# Do clicked cookies still count after a reset?

Tags: cookie-clicker

I picked up cookie clicker again. I am trying to get some achievements as fast as possible.

One of those achievements is `Make 1 quadrillion cookies from clicking.`.

Right now I am on `75.123 billion cookies clicked`.

If I reset(not wipe) the game, do I have to start over again with clicking or does it continue where I left?

Comment: I suspect cookie clicker being a secret experiment by manufacturers of computer mice such as M$ or Logitech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My extremely basic test involving 25 clicks resulted in an answer you won't like, resetting *does* wipe the stat "cookies clicked". The only thing that stays is cookies baked (all time), and "cookies forfeited" goes up with the amount of cookies you gave up.
So, just keep clicking without resetting.